# current input value not show in another input value

Tags: jquery

i'm new to jquery
when i use thes code didn't work
where the error

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script >
            $("#total").keyup(function() {
                $("#total2").val($("#total").val());
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="total" type="text" ></td>
        <td><input id="total2" type="text" ></td>
    </tr>
</body>
```

Comment: How does it not work? What should it do? What does it do instead?

Comment: when i type number not show in the second input

Comment: it should do when i type number in first input "total" it show in second input "total2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using $().ready function.

Like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#total").keyup(function() {
     $("#total2").val($("#total").val());
   }); 
});
```

Read this:
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/